# Backticks in JavaScript file not auto closing in VSCode

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, autocomplete, visual-studio-code, backticks

When I am editing a JavaScript file inside VSCode and try using the backticks (`` ` ``) it won't auto close. I want to have the same auto-closing feature that I have with the quotation marks, where if I type `"` I get:

```
"|"
```

(`|` = my cursor)

I have tried disabling all my extensions and that didn't solve it. If I try it inside Atom it works just fine.I'm using a Belgian keyboard layout on Mac.

A now-deleted answer referred to [this fixed bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26820), but unfortunately for me, typing a space after the backtick (as [described in the fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26820#issuecomment-395604359)) just leaves me with a backtick and a space.

Comment: Excellent inclusion of detail in the question. Nice one!

Comment: That's weird, for me backticks are autocompleting, I tried to run vs code without extensions (`code . --disable-extensions`) to be sure it was not one of them making the autocomplete and I still have the autocompletions. Which version are you using ? (help > about or `code -v`)

Comment: You didn't change this setting: "editor.autoClosingQuotes": "languageDefined" - I believe that is the default, if I change it to "never" the backticks don't autocomplete.  But with "languageDefined" they do.  You could also try "always".

Comment: Try typing a space before the backtick, in my case it doesn't automatically close if it immediately follows a character. Of course it's not ideal, but with auto formatting the space gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried to find a way around this, but at least on my system (set to German) the behavior described seems to come from the fact that by default the backtick (`) is a dead key, meaning it will not produce a character until the next key is hit. Funnily enough, the backtick that you see on screen is thus actually created *because* VSCode tries to auto-complete the backtick (with another backtick), but the initial character is swallowed (because there is no such thing as an accented accent, which is what that key is generally used for).

If I type a space after the backtick, it gets auto-completed though. Running VSCode 1.36.0 on MacOS.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `"editor.autoClosingQuotes": "always"` in VSCode settings fixed this for me.

**EDIT:** After using this for a couple of weeks it got really annoying always deleting the second quote when it added it even in inappropriate places, like at the beginning or middle of words. This is still the best solution I know of, but it's not perfect.